# I want to sort parent node CommlCoverage , based on child's name of From Tag

Tags: xslt

we want to xsl-sort of from element in

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<General><CommlCoverage>
    <Audit>
            <AuditMtc>
                    <Term>
                            <From>2013-07-05</From>
                            <To>2014-06-02</To>
                    </Term>
            </AuditMtc>
    </Audit>
    <Supplement>
            <Audit>
                    <AuditMtc>
                            <Term>
                                    <From>2013-07-02</From>
                                    <To>2014-06-02</To>
                            </Term>
                    </AuditMtc>
            </Audit>
    </Supplement>
    <Supplement>
            <Audit>
                    <AuditMtc>
                            <Term>
                                    <From>2013-01-02</From>
                                    <To>2014-06-02</To>
                            </Term>
                    </AuditMtc>
            </Audit>
    </Supplement>
</CommlCoverage>    
<CommlCoverage>
<Audit>
<AuditMtc><Term><From>2013-07-05</From><To>2014-06-02</To></Term></AuditMtc></Audit>
<Supplement><Audit><AuditMtc><Term><From>2013-07-02</From><To>2014-06-02</To></Term></AuditMtc></Audit></Supplement>
</CommlCoverage></General>
```

need to sorting based on date first tag Audit having different structure with date second Supplement tag having different structure with different date 
My code:

```
            <xsl:for-each select="CommlCoverage">
            <xsl:sort select="From"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="Audit">
                <xsl:value-of select="AuditMtc/Term/From"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="Supplement/Audit">
                <xsl:value-of select="AuditMtc/Term/From"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
We have update the desired output:
[2013-01-02 To 2014-06-02]
[2013-01-02 To 2014-06-02]
[2013-07-02 To 2014-06-02] [2013-07-02 To 2014-06-02] [2013-07-05 To 2014-06-02] [2013-07-05 To 2014-06-02]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the question correctly. Can you clarify what you mean by "different structure", and give an example of how you would want these sorted and why?

Comment: different structure as: "CommlCoverage/Audit/AuditMtc/Term/From" and second is "CommlCoverage/Supplement/Audit/AuditMtc/Term/From"

Comment: need to 
[2013-01-02 To 2014-06-02]  
[2013-07-02 To 2014-06-02]  
[2013-07-05 To 2014-06-02]

Comment: And I'm also use this code
<xsl:for-each select="CommlCoverage">
<xsl:sort select="From"/>

<xsl:for-each select="Audit">
<xsl:value-of select="AuditMtc/Term/From"/>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="Supplement/Audit">
<xsl:value-of select="AuditMtc/Term/From"/>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:for-each>

Comment: Can you edit your question to include all this information, rather than add it as comments? The question should ideally show your current input, your expected output, and the code you have currently tried. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could ask someone proficient in English to help you reword the question?

Comment: Please can you edit your question to show the exact output you expect for the input XML you have shown. Currently you have six "From" and "To" dates showing in your expected output, but the input XML only has five. Also, are you definitely outputting only text here, and not XML? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably start off by having a template to match the root element

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
```

Within this, you then just need to select the **Term** children in order of their **From** date, which could be at different levels. (This assumes the **From** element is always a direct child of **Term**

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Term">
    <xsl:sort select="From" />
 </xsl:apply-templates>
```

Note that the syntax `.//Term` will search for **Term** elements at any level in the hierarchy below the current node.

Then, you just need a template to match the **Term** elements, and output the **From** and **To** values, like so

```
  <xsl:template match="Term">
    [<xsl:value-of select="From"/> to <xsl:value-of select="To" />]
  </xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Term">
         <xsl:sort select="From" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Term">
    [<xsl:value-of select="From"/> to <xsl:value-of select="To" />]
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This outputs the following:

```
[2013-01-02 to 2014-06-02]
[2013-07-02 to 2014-06-02]
[2013-07-02 to 2014-06-02]
[2013-07-05 to 2014-06-02]
[2013-07-05 to 2014-06-02]
```

(This doesn't quite match your expected output, because your expected output shows six lots of From and To times, but only five are in your input).

Comment: I have simplified by answer based on your expected output in the question. There is no need to do a xsl:for-each on "CommlCoverage" as it the root element, and so there is only one of them. It is the descendant elements you are sorting.

Comment: @KamleshGupta Please accept this answer (mark the tick on the left) if it solved your problem.

Comment: Sir actually , can u write a code on loop because "CommlCoverage" is coming multiple times , so I want to do with loop.

Comment: You need to edit your question to show an example of this because at the "CommlCoverage" element is the root element, and so can only occur once for the XML to be well-formed. If you give an example of some XML with multiple "CommlCoverage" elements, and the output you expect in this case, I am sure the code can be changed to cope.

Comment: we have facing the problem with From tag because it's two different tag of descendent "CommlCoverage/Audit" and "CommlCoverage/Supplement/Audit". please help :)

Comment: I am afraid I am bit confused. The solution I have provided copes with that situation, and given the XML you have shown, produces the output you expect, so I am not clear what the issue is. Is the XML in your question definitely the XML you are actually using then? If it isn't, you will need to edit the question to show a more representative sample. Thank you!

Comment: Dear Sir, Now I have update the above xml and i want to loop with "CommlCoverage" because I want to sort with From And To tags but problem is that From and To tags come in different path first is   "CommlCoverage/Audit/AuditMtc/Term/From" and second is "CommlCoverage/Supplement/Audit/AuditMtc/Term/From" i want loop with  "CommlCoverage". and xsl:sort not allow the descendent node.

Comment: Thanks. That is looking better. Can you also show the output that corresponds to the new XML? Or is the output the same as currently shown? (That is to say, do you want duplicate From and To times to be removed?)

Comment: no, d'nt removed the duplicate From and To tag do the sort all From and To tags as ascending order..

Comment: Sir I have update the xml and desired output please help anyone :)

Comment: @KamleshGupta I have amended my answer to show more clearly how it can handle the dates in any order that should hopefully give you the output you need.

Comment: I am getting Error: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the @select attribute of xsl:sort' error with sort function because I want use the xsl:sort in xsl:for-each.

Comment: Are you getting the error using the exact XSLT I have given in my answer, or have you changed it in some way? If you have made a change, it might help to say what the change was (in particular, what is the @select attribute of xsl:sort set to). I tested my XSLT at http://www.xmlplayground.com/GtYina and it appears to work fine if you take a look. Thanks!

Comment: We are using this xslt...actually it is some part of my requirement because ,we are unable to showing the original data, sorry.
<xsl:for-each select="CommlCoverage">
            <xsl:sort select="From"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="Audit">
                <xsl:value-of select="AuditMtc/Term/From"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="Supplement/Audit">
                <xsl:value-of select="AuditMtc/Term/From"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
We want sort the From.

Comment: The answer provided does sort on the **From**. It selects all **Term** elements, regardless of where they are in the hierarchy, and sorts them by **From** before outputting them. There is no need to sort on **CommlCoverage** here if you are only interested in outputting **From** and **To** values. As mentioned above, if you go to http://www.xmlplayground.com/GtYina you can see it in action. Thanks!

Comment: as use my above my xslt : when sort "Supplement/Audit/AuditMtc/Term/From" than show the error as "XTTE1020: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the @select attribute of xsl:sort."

Comment: we want to sort the both **From** tag that existing in **Supplement** and **CommlCoverage** tags. Sir actually this is the some part of my requirement. we are unable to show the exact data. sorry... if possible than please help in xsl:for-each loop.

Comment: as per my required necessary to use the **for-each** in **xsl:sort** , is that possible to use sort in loop.

Comment: You may not be able to show the exact data, that is fine. But you need to edit your question to show a representative sample of the data, as well as the exact output you require from the sample you provide. Thank you.

Comment: Sir your above code is working properly as per xml but we want to sort in **CommlCoverage** loop and when use this '<xsl:sort select="//Term/From"/>' this is not working and showing the error **XTTE1020: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the @select attribute of xsl:sort**. we want compound sort of **From** tag that exist in "CommlCoverage/Audit/AuditMtc/Term/From" and second is "CommlCoverage/**Supplement**/Audit/AuditMtc/Term/From"

Comment: we want to sort from **CommlCoverage** level to **From** tag and show the error because each **CommlCoverage** in the exist the multiple **Supplement** if in **CommlCoverage** exist the only one **Audit** or  **Supplement** than run properly in loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm right about the requirement, but, this is what the following code does:
Sorts "CommlCoverage" based on any //Term/From and then writes all //Term/From in sorted order.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/General">
    <xsl:for-each select="CommlCoverage">
        <xsl:sort>
            <xsl:for-each select="current()//Term/From">
                <xsl:sort select="."/>
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:sort>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Audit | Supplement/Audit">
            <xsl:sort select="AuditMtc/Term/From"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:text>
        </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Audit">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('[', AuditMtc/Term/From, ' To ', AuditMtc/Term/To, ']')"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: output produced when ran your input XML against above xslt:
[2013-01-02 To 2014-06-02][2013-07-02 To 2014-06-02][2013-07-05 To 2014-06-02]
[2013-07-02 To 2014-06-02][2013-07-05 To 2014-06-02]